# Meteor + Iron Router: Load FlowPlayer once template has finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, iron-router, flowplayer

I'm using Meteor and FlowPlayer (https://flowplayer.org/docs/api.html#load-method) to load a videos based on the selection the user makes. I'd like the to initialise FlowPlayer once the Template and {{video}} data has loaded. As I get the following errors in console:

GET http://cdn.flowplayer.org/276539/.webm 404 (Not Found)
*Looks like the data hasn't loaded yet and the Video object has loaded.*

If the user makes a new selection; then I need to kill the current FlowPlayer and reinitialise it with the new {{video}} tag data on the new route otherwise the old selected video is still playing.

What's the best way of going about solving this?

**HTML**

```
<template name="lessonVideo">
  <div class="container p-t-1">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 text-xs-center">
        <h4>Lesson <span class="text-uppercase">{{eachLessonId}}</span></h4>
        <h5 class="text-muted">{{title}}</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row p-t-1">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-md-push-2 col-md-pull-2 center-block">
        <div class="flowplayer embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
           <video class="embed-responsive-item" poster="//drive.cdn.flowplayer.org/276539/{{video}}-snap.jpg">
             <source type="application/x-mpegurl" src="//cdn.flowplayer.org/276539/{{video}}.m3u8">
             <source type="video/webm" src="//cdn.flowplayer.org/276539/{{video}}.webm">
             <source type="video/mp4" src="//cdn.flowplayer.org/276539/{{video}}.mp4">
             <source type="video/flash" src="mp4:276539/{{video}}.mp4">
           </video>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div><!-- end .container -->
</template>
```

**Route**

```
Router.route('/courses/:courseId/:lessonId/:eachLessonId', {
  name: 'lessons',
  layoutTemplate: 'layoutLessons',
  template: 'lessonVideo',
  onBeforeAction: function() {
    let currentUser = Meteor.userId();
    if (currentUser)  {
      Session.set('courseId', this.params.courseId);
      Session.set('eachLessonId', this.params.eachLessonId);
      console.log('Each Lesson ID set: '+Session.get('eachLessonId'));
      this.next();
    } else {
      Router.go('/');
    }
  },
  data: function() {
    var doc = Lessons.findOne({
      "courseId": this.params.courseId,
      "lesson.lessonId": this.params.lessonId,
      "lesson.eachLesson.eachLessonId": this.params.eachLessonId
    });
    if (doc) {
      var lesson = {};
      var lessonId = this.params.eachLessonId;
      _.each(doc.lesson, function(i) {
        lesson = _.find(i.eachLesson, function(j) {
          return j.eachLessonId == lessonId;
        });
      });
      return lesson;
    }
    return {};
  },
  onAfterAction: function() {
    $(".flowplayer").flowplayer();
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onAfterAction: function() {
    $(".flowplayer").flowplayer();
  },
```

This initialize the flowplayer before the page render. So class flowplayer was not there when you initialized the flowplayer. You can solve this problem by initialize the flowplayer after page render. So it will be like ..

```
Template.lessonVideo.onRendered(function() {
  $(".flowplayer").flowplayer();
});
```

You can reinitialize the floweplayer using autorun, that re run the code when some reactive data changes. So whenever your params change it will reinitialize your player. like this

```
Template.lessonVideo.onRendered(function() {
    var self = this;
    this.autorun(function() {
      if(this.params.lessonId){ //please your params that will reflect the video.
        $('#side-menu').metisMenu();
      }
    });
})
```

Comment: How do I kill flowplayer and reinitialize it when a new route is selected; to load a new video?